# Ice WM scale too small

Tags: icewm

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I recently installed the Ice WM window manager.

I ran into such a problem that everything is very, very small. Difficult to read, and generally something to see. I dug through all the settings, but could not find where to change the scale.
Can you please tell me if this can be done and how?

Comment: ICE WM is a very slim, pixel based Window Manager. You may tweak it individually as described [here](https://github.com/bbidulock/icewm/issues/288)

Comment: Scaling requires later toolkits that ICE-WM doesn't use; they didn't exist when ICE WM was created & it's not been altered to make use of them (*it'd change what ICE WM was intended for rather significantly in my opinion*)  ... don't forget its OSF/Motif type roots